# Angular2 - Filter Array of object where property is not in values

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having some troubles while filtering an array of objects based on a set of values:

This is the array to be filtered:

```
var items: Product[] = ... values
```

Now I declare an array of the products that I want to select:

```
var sel: Product[] = ... values
```

The property on which I have to apply the filter is **idProduct**, how can I do it?

I need something like this:

```
var query = items.filter( x => x.idProduct IN (List of idProduct from sel Array)
```

How can I do it?

Thanks to support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `some` to find any product in `sel` with the same product id

```
items.filter(i=> sel.some(s=> s.idProduct == i.idProduct));
```

Comment: where does sel come from? its a standard feature ?

Comment: My understanding was you already had a an array `sel` of products, and you wanted to filter another array using it

Answer (score 1):

Based on the other answers but using [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

`let query = items.filter(x => sel.map(y => y.idProduct).includes(x.idProduct));`